# Writing a DynamoDB Map object in JSON

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add values to a table using a JSON document, but keep getting errors. What is wrong with my JSON spec?

- topic is a string (key)
- question is a map of a question/answer

I keep getting:

Error:

when I run `aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://notesTable.json`:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.notesTable[0].PutRequest.Item.questions.
M, value: [OrderedDict([('what is Dynamo?', OrderedDict([('S', 'a non-relational
 document based NoSQL database')]))])], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <clas
s 'dict'>
```

GOAL:

```
topics    questions
------    ---------
Dynamo    {"what is Dynamo?":{"S":"a non-relational document based NoSQL database"}}
```

JSON structure

```
{
    "notesTable": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "topic":{"S":"Dynamo"},
                    "questions": {
                        "M": [
                            {"what is Dynamo?":{"S":"a non-relational document based NoSQL database"}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB JSON Format is different from regular json format. According to your goal, the formatted json should be something similar to this:

```
{
"notesTable": [
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {                    
              "topic": {
                "S": "Dynamo"
              },
              "questions": {
                "L": [
                  {
                    "M": {
                      "what is Dynamo?": {
                        "S": "a non-relational document based NoSQL database"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

There are online tools to convert regular json to dynamo json. You could try with this:
https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-json-converter-tool/

Comment: You can also use the marshal and unmarshall functions in the util class of the SDKs to go between regular JSON and DynamoDB JSON if you are using the SDKs.

Comment: @ORP when I try this I get:

`
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.notesTable, value: OrderedDict([('L', [O
rderedDict([('M', OrderedDict([('PutRequest', OrderedDict([('M', OrderedDict([('
Item', OrderedDict([('M', OrderedDict([('topic', OrderedDict([('S', 'Dynamo')]))
, ('questions', OrderedDict([('L', [OrderedDict([('M', OrderedDict([('what is Dy
namo?', OrderedDict([('S', 'a non-relational document based NoSQL database')]))]
))])])]))]))]))]))]))]))])])]), type: <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, valid t
ypes: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>
`

Comment: I haven't noticed that you are using batch-write-item option. I have just updated the answer code with the correct structure. Please try again